# Is titanium chromium alloy an insulator or a conductor?

Tags: conductors, insulators

I want to get some copper parts made, and the maker of the parts says they can coat the parts with a PVD (physical vapor deposition) process using a coating of Titanium and Chromium.

I need the parts to be electrically insulated. I thought that both Titanium and Chromium were conductors, but
this [website](https://www.pvd-coatings.co.uk/coatings/ceramic-coatings/) says "The most common *ceramic* coatings available are TiN, CrN, TiCN, and TiAlN."

Is the Titanium and Chromium coating an insulator when applied as a PVD coating? Is the coating a true insulator, or just much less electrically conductive than other conductors?

Comment: Certainly TiN is a conductor, as likely are TiCN and TiAlN. Not sure about CrN. Many metal nitrides/carbides/oxides are actually conducting (less so the oxides).

Comment: The very thin coatings, likely with holidays , will not have significant electrical resistance.